# How to search mysql for different words situated in different places in a string

Tags: php, mysql

For example, someone search for `black shirt size 16` and we have a row (which column name is shirt_title) in mysql table containing `black shirt for men and size is 17`. The following query will search for an exact word but not for different combinations of words stated above.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT shirt_title FROM product WHERE shirt_title LIKE ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, "%$search_str%");
```

Should I use array? If so, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be

```
$keywords = 'black shirt size 16';
$keywords = explode(' ', $keywords);

$queryStr = array();
foreach($keywords as $k => $keyword){
    $keywords[$k] = "%{$keyword}%";
    $queryStr[] = 'shirt_title LIKE ?';
}
$queryStr = implode(' AND ', $queryStr);

...

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT shirt_title FROM product WHERE {$queryStr}");
$stmt->execute($keywords);
```

Although  I believe there must be a more efficient way, because the things I have heard about `LIKE` are not very pleasant.