# MySQL search query for best text match

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm trying to make better search experience for users, we have lots of long titles for products like:

"*Loptop Acer V3-772 17.3" HD+ / Intel Core i7-4702MQ iki 3.2Ghz / 4Gb DDR3 1600Mhz / 1Tb HDD / GeForce GTX850 2Gb DDR5 / WiFi / HDMI / Bluetooth / HD camera/ USB 3.0*"

So, if client is looking for: "**Acer 4Gb 1Tb i7**" loptop, with MySQL function LIKE %...% it founds it fast, but if one result like "*i7*" is not located, query gives 0 results.

We're trying to make search by every search keyword, then count with ones gave most results, and search in them for 2 and 3 combined LIKE words.

Or there is any easier solution for this all search to come true?

**UPDATE:** Hi guys,
So I got solution for my quest - full text search with minimal 1 symbol, reconfigured in my.ini file, so it looks for "i7" and all other small searches as it should, thanks for help :)

Comment: Have you tried a full-text search?

Comment: What code have you currently got?

Comment: Yes, there is two parts of search, first full-text, second like, now I want to make it just one normal search function.

Simply lost at trying to make that search, lots of googling, and this is my last resort to ask.

Comment: @j08691: Fulltext search is optimized for “natural” language – with short search terms like “i7” here you will run into its limitations rights away.

Comment: @CBroe - The short "i7" term issue can be fixed by changing the ft_min_word_len to 2.

Comment: That will have performance implications. And with other terms that are present in a lot of records (like the manufacturer name), there will also be issues.

Comment: @j08691 - full text search is limited with some languages, and my language is one of them. If there is any solution for, most usefulness result to be dropped from query, and search without it, that would be the solution.

Comment: I think your issue is almost same as mine. I got a useful answer. Have a look here, [How to search mysql for different words situated in different places in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813676/how-to-search-mysql-for-different-words-situated-in-different-places-in-a-string)

Comment: You're doing this wrong anyway, do a search based on features, and extrapolate what you can from the search into features, rather than searching text for "Acer 4GB 1TB i7" search the Manufacturer for Acer, the RAM for 4GB, the storage for 1TB and the processor for i7. Lexical searches yield faster and more intelligent results than brute force. Also weight your results and build relationship mappings, someone searching for Acer isn't likely to want an apple product, but 4GB of ram could easily be satisfied with a 6GB or 8GB machine instead.

Comment: @HasibMahmud - gonna try that solution.

Comment: @scragar - we have lot of IT products, not only laptops, so this search for attributes would load some time, and search is "suggestion" type.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211812/how-to-sort-mysql-results-by-most-matches-when-using-like

Comment: @PatrickQ - thank you for linking to similar question. Gonna try all suggestions, if any will help, will share that code for future "myselfs"

Answer (score 0):

A better do what you're trying to achieve:

```
$search_key = $_POST['searchkey'];  //take the search text from the post method

$search_words = array();
$search_words = explode(" ",$search_key);



$q_string = "";
$last_index = intval(count($search_Words)) - 1;

for($i = 0; $i<count($search_Words);$i++)
  {
    $q_string = $q_string . " description LIKE '%$search_words[$i]%' ";
    if($i != $last_index)
      $q_string = $q_string . " OR ";

   }
```

Then at the last

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ".$q_string);
```

NOTE:
Assuming that the `description` field contatins detail of the product in the table table_name

Comment: Thank you for your time, as I mentioned in my question, now I'm using full-text search, and it works great.